# Errors running celery with Django

Tags: python, django, celery

This is my project structure:

```
fj_project
|-- fj
|   |-- celerybeat.pid
|   |-- celerybeat-schedule
|   |-- celeryconfig.pyc
|   |-- fe
|   |   |-- admin.py
|   |   |-- forms.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- models.py
|   |   |-- tasks.py
|   |   |-- tests.py
|   |   |-- views.py
|   |-- FeJa
|   |   |-- celeryconfig.pyc
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- settings
|   |   |   |-- base.py
|   |   |   |-- celeryconfig.py
|   |   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |   |-- local.py
|   |   |   |-- production.py
|   |   |   |-- tasks.py
|   |   |   `-- test.py
|   |   |-- urls.py
|   |   |-- wsgi.py
|   |-- fj.sqlite3
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- site-media
|   `-- templates
|       |-- 400.html
|-- Makefile
`-- requirements
    |-- local.txt
     -- production.txt
```

I start celery from the settings directory. And it starts but doesn't add the tasks mentioned in the fe directory. This is my celeryconfig file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta

app = Celery('fj',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

I am unable to figure out how to make celery discover tasks in all the directories and sub-directories. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can autodscover tasks by invoking autodiscover_tasks() on an instance of Celery class:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(['fe'])
```

First argument is a list of packages to search and keyword argument "related_name" can contain name of a module holding tasks (default is "tasks").

List of packages to search can be django's INSTALLED_APPS list.

Here the [documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=autodiscover_tasks#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks) for autodiscover_tasks()

Comment: I did write the above line. It gives "no module named 'fe'". I think its because of the settings folder I'm using.